# Call function of directive inside another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, polymer

I want to make a Calendar so i want to have a Calender directive with multipe Event directives in it and calendar should manage those. i am not that familar with angular, so i think i do something totally wrong. In Polymer something like that should work.

Actually i handle directives somewhat like objects but i think i can't call methods like that. Could someone give me an example of how to manage multiple directives within another or if that is not meant to be possible;

Currently i am getting event.start() is not a function.

### [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cVvA5aYzWSU4ym4HUMcX?p=preview)

```
angular.module("Calendar").directive('calevent',[function(){
function link(scope,element,attrs){

    scope.start = new Date(scope.start);
    scope.end = new Date(scope.end);
    scope.height = Math.round((((end-start)% 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000)/60*20;
    element[0].querySelector(".event").style.height = height + "px";
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    element[0].querySelector(".event").style.top = (Math.round((((start.getTime()-d.getTime())% 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000)/60*20) + "px";

    function updateProgress(){
        var cur = new Date();
        var diff = (cur.getTime()-start.getTime())/ (end.getTime()-start.getTime())
        diff = (diff < 1) ? diff : height;
        element[0].querySelector(".eventProgress").style.height =  (height*diff) + "px";
    }

    function start(){
        return start;
    }

    function end(){
        return end;
    }
}

return  {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
        text:"=",
        start:"=",
        end:"=",
    },
    templateUrl:'event.html',
    link:link
}
}]);
```

I want to call updateProgress() for a specific event from EventCalendar directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `controller` in your parent directive.

If you visit the end of the directive [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), you can find an example of how to do this.

I saved their example in a Plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/teOkiuc1kMQaedu0AXpU?p=preview).

In short, you define a controller in your directive, which exposes functions on $scope. The child directives can then use them.

Comment: pointed me to right direction. For those interested my working sample http://plnkr.co/edit/5Iyq61aZpL1H3JVTVJQU     bad quality but working

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) option, it allows you to work inside the directive and put content inside also another directive.